# Why use Bootstrap's .w-100 class to split a row's columns into two rows, when you could just make two rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

On this page in the Bootstrap documentation at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row they give this example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

This creates two rows with two equal-sized columns in each row. However, you can achieve this just by creating two rows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col</div>
  <div class="col">col</div>
</div>
```

Is there any difference between using the `.w-100` CSS class and just creating two rows instead?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this specific case, there is no difference.

However, keeping **the cols in a single `.row` is generally better** for these reasons...

**Column ordering**

Suppose you instead want to switch the order of the first and last columns on `md` and up. This would not be possible with separate `.row` containers. Keeping all the `col` in a single `.row` makes it possible.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col flex-md-last">col 1</div>
    <div class="col">col 2</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col">col 3</div>
    <div class="col flex-md-first">col 4</div>
</div>
```

---

**Responsive layouts**

Another example. Suppose you instead wanted a layout of:

- 4 cols across 1 row on `md` width (4x1)
- 2 cols across 2 rows on `xs` width (2x2)

Again, this would not be possible with separate `.row` divs. But, since the `w-100` can be used responsively, this is possible by keeping all the cols in a single row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">col 1</div>
    <div class="col col-md-3">col 2</div>
    <div class="w-100 hidden-md-up"></div>
    <div class="col col-md-3">col 3</div>
    <div class="col col-md-3">col 4</div>
</div>
```

[Demo of the layouts](http://www.codeply.com/go/5fVEzEq16H)

Comment: `hidden-md-up` has been removed from the latest versions of bootstrap. You need to have `d-md-none` on the later versions [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)